# Using XmlResourceParser to parse xml file in internal storage

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have an application where at one stage, I need to download the latest xml file from a server and store it in internal storage (data/data/packagename/filename.xml). I've searched online and its not possible to save file at runtime to res folder, so I have to use internal storage.

However, I'm struggling to try and parse the xml file. Previously I've been using the XmlResourceParser to parse static xml already stored in res/xml/ folder. It's very easy to use. So I'm wondering if theres a way to use XmlResourceParser to parse the newly downloaded xml file. Otherwise, how should I parse the xml file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XmlResourceParser` is for binary xml files in `res` folder only. But you can use [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html). It can read data from an `InputStream`.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I've had a look at XmlPullParser but it seems like its an interface. Does that mean that I have to create a class that implements it first? Do you know any good tutorial on this?

Comment: If you open a link from my answer and scroll a page down a little you'll see an example of using this interface. BTW you don't have to implement this interface. Just create a factory using `XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance()` and then create an instance of the parser with `factory.newPullParser()`.